# REST API model bind for complex model + collection + IFormFile

Tags: c#, .net, rest, model-binding

I have an action that should take as a parameter complex model. It should contain following properties which should be model binded:

1. IFormFile (binding already done)
2. string properties (binding already done)
3. dictionary

I have problems with binding to Metadata collection of UploadHeaders class. None of the ways I tried works. I tried FormUrlEncodedContent and StringContent (as JSON). Can somebody point me into right direction how to, apart from IFormFile and string properties, also bind a collection? FileMetadata object is a collection of class that has only Key and Value properties. Both are public.

Server side:

Action model:

```
public class UploadHeaders
{
    public IFormFile File { get; set; }

    public IList<FileMetadata> Metadata { get; set; }

    public string Author { get; set; }

    public int AuthorId { get; set; }

    public UploadHeaders()
    {
        this.Metadata = new List<FileMetadata>();
    }
}
```

Action:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Upload([FromForm] UploadHeaders uploadHeaders)
{ 
...
}
```

Cient side method that calls server side Upload action:

```
static UploadResponse Upload(string fileToUpload, string fileName)
    {
        var multipartFormDataContent = new MultipartFormDataContent();
        var fileContent = new ByteArrayContent(File.ReadAllBytes(fileToUpload));
        multipartFormDataContent.Add(fileContent, "file", fileName);
        multipartFormDataContent.Add(new StringContent("Author"), "Author");
        multipartFormDataContent.Add(new StringContent("13"), "AuthorId");

        var metadataStringContent = new FormUrlEncodedContent(
            new []
            {
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Metadata[0].Key", "key1"),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Metadata[0].Value", "value1")
            }
        );

        multipartFormDataContent.Add(metadataStringContent, "meta");

        var response = httpClient.PostAsync(httpClient.BaseAddress + "Upload", multipartFormDataContent).Result;

        string stringResult = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
        UploadResponse uploadResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<UploadResponse>(stringResult);
        Console.WriteLine("{0} to {1}, result {2}", fileToUpload, fileName, uploadResponse.Id);
        return uploadResponse;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

In order to bind collection you should to pass its values as `StringContent` as well

```
var multipartFormDataContent = new MultipartFormDataContent();
var fileContent = new ByteArrayContent(File.ReadAllBytes(fileToUpload));
multipartFormDataContent.Add(fileContent, "file", fileName);
multipartFormDataContent.Add(new StringContent("Author"), "Author");
multipartFormDataContent.Add(new StringContent("13"), "AuthorId");

// parameter name should follow this template
// {collection_name}[{index}].{property}
multipartFormDataContent.Add(new StringContent("key1"), "Metadata[0].Key");
multipartFormDataContent.Add(new StringContent("value1"), "Metadata[0].Value");
```